# How to tell Vue typescript parser the relationship between two types in a generic template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create a generic template in Vue 3.4 that handles displaying a field on a page.  I have typescript types that describe the relevant variables:

```
export enum FieldType {
  Text,
  Checkbox,
} 

export type FieldDescription<T extends FieldType> = {
  label: string,
  type: T,
}

export type FieldComponentModelType<T extends FieldType> =
  T extends FieldType.Text ? string :
  T extends FieldType.Checkbox ? boolean :
  never;
```

I am then attempting to create the generic template like so:

```
<template>
  <TextField v-if="props.field.type===FieldType.Text"
    v-model="model"
    :label="props.field.label"
  />
  <CheckField v-if="props.field.type===FieldType.Checkbox"
    v-model="model"
    :label="props.field.label"
  />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts" generic="T extends FieldType">  
  const props = defineProps({
    field: {
      type: Object as PropType<FieldDescription<T>>,
      required: true,
    },
  });

  const model = defineModel<FieldComponentModelType<T>>({ required: true });
</script>
```

It works fine, but I get a typescript error on the v-model assignment in the template: `Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'` (or vice versa for the checkbox case).  I think what's happening is that the Vue Typescript parser isn't able to see that the TextField block is only called when T is Text and thus model must be a string (because FieldComponentModelType<FieldType.Text> is string).

Is there some way to refactor this to avoid the error while still providing typechecking of v-model vs. the prop on components that use this one?  Or I suppose alternately to just tell it to ignore the error?